# Can I jailbreak an iPhone 4S with iOS 8.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 8.2 and I want to jailbreak it.
Is there is a jailbreak for this iOS version?

Comment: There might be a jailbreak 27 March for iOS 8.2 according so anonymous sources.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [on iPhoneHacks.com](http://www.iphonehacks.com/ios-8-2):

> It is currently not possible to jailbreak iOS 8.2.